# Prepared statements example

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In this new system I am currently writing (whilst learning PHP), I've been trying to use prepared statements but could not find an example that allowed me to get this piece of code to work. After spending some considerable time on it, I have written it without prepared statements (otherwise I would still be stuck).

However, if anyone would be kind enough to enlighten me as to how I would achieve the same functionality using prepared statements, that would be great. I am using prepared statements for `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s, but have not managed to get one to work using `SELECT`.

This piece of code is an AJAX page to populate a dropdown list based on a selection on the page.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('assets/includes/config.php');

if ((!isset($_GET['cat']) || !is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) && (!isset($_GET['subcat']) || !is_numeric($_GET['subcat'])))
    $response = array('success' => FALSE);
else {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($config["db"]["host"],$config["db"]["dbname"],$config["db"]["password"],$config["db"]["username"]);
    $cat= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['cat']);
    $subcat= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['subcat']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM jf_data WHERE cat = $cat and subcat = $subcat;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $options = "";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
        $options .= '<option value="'. $row['id'] .'">'. $row['data'].'</option>';
    }
    $response = array(
        'success' => TRUE,
        'options' => $options
    );
    }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give this a whirl:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($config["db"]["host"],$config["db"]["username"],$config["db"]["password"],$config["db"]["dbname"]);

$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$subcat = $_GET['subcat'];
$options = '';

$sql = "SELECT id,data FROM jf_data WHERE cat = ? and subcat = ?;";

if($stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($conn,$sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$cat,$subcat);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$id,$data);

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
        $options .= '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $data . '</option>';
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

$response = array(
    'success' => TRUE,
    'options' => $options
);
```

Here is the list of questions and answers:

- *Why don't I need to clean my `$_GET` statments?* - the binding takes care of all that for you, no need for escaping strings (which never worked well anyway)
- *What is the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` stuff?* - Those are the items you need to include: statement executed, datatypes in order of question mark ('ss' is string, string), variable 1, variable 2 (variables in order of the question mark)
- *What is the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` stuff?* - That is the data you get back. Notice I did not do a `SELECT *` (which is a terrible idea in any scenario, always specify your columns), i only needed two items which are then bound to the result variables `$id` and `$data` that I created
- *Where is all the `$row` array stuff that I'm used to?* - It's gone! Bound statements do not go based on rows using MYSQLI_ASSOC or anything weird like that, just straight variables
- *Why do you close your statement?* - because you always should. always.

I don't mean to come across as mean or anything, these are a combinations of questions I had when I first started, and questions I've encountered when explaining it to others. Just figured I'd give a good baseline to start with. Another good validation is to [read the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), which always has examples of how to implement this (go to the procedural style, Example #2).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT: Connection advice**

Personally, I like to keep my connection setup in a separate file so that I can just add the require in rather than maintaining code across different pages. You have it set up in an array, but the same logic applies. I usually set up a separate `mysqli_[appname]_SUID.php` file (for users that have full SUID access) like this:

```
$host="localhost";

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'www.domain.com'){ // production DB
    $username="production_user";
    $password="production_password";
    $db_name="production_db";
} else { // dev or stage DB
    $username="dev_user";
    $password="dev_password";
    $db_name="dev_db";
}

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
```

This allows pretty easy modification, and whenever you need to use it, just add in the require:

```
require_once 'requires/mysqli_[appname]_SUID.php';
```

And you're good to go. Not sure if that helps too, just my practice.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely not mean. Helpful questions (and answers). The example will be useful for reusing later on.

Comment: Although I am getting this: Warning: mysqli_stmt_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given in xxx on line 15 - this is on the 'if($stmt' line

Comment: @Graeme - sorry, didn't notice this before, your `mysqli_connect()` statement was out of order. It needs to go `mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);` I've updated my answer with the correct order, and a link to the documentation with an example setup.